# Is it possible using the Graph API to synchronize posts on a FB Group <--> External Site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-group

Just browsing the API and I'm a bit unclear on this.  I'll need to dig more to figure it out, but I wanted to know if anyone else out there has done this.  Seems like Facebook Groups mimic bulletin boards but are more robust.  I'd like to at least be able to synchronize comments and  import group posts perhaps under something like TOPIC >> FACEBOOK POSTS.  Would be a huge win for the dying world of bulletin boards to piggyback on a Facebook sync so that people can post in the FB group and have others receive notifications while some kind of implementation of the  [Facebook Realtime Updates API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). Imports new posts from the Facebook page so that new users or those not on Facebook can also participate in the discussion.  The tough part of course would be synchronizing the respective post ID's and their comments on the forum <--> Facebook.

Has this been done, and more importantly is it allowed?  Does it violate Facebook terms & conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my inquiry is pretty similar to this one

[Get data from a facebook page wall or group wall for use on personal website](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3417868/get-data-from-a-facebook-page-wall-or-group-wall-for-use-on-personal-website)

Just in case I don't get a better answer and someone else finds this question...